# How to change cassandra standalone mode to distributed

Tags: cassandra

I have installed Cassandra 2.1 stand alone mode in two nodes seperately.

Is there any way to change both to distributed or make both the node used in one cluster.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

I also suggest taking a look at this hands on training course: https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds201-cassandra-core-concepts

It's free and definitely worth your time if you're thinking about using Cassandra in production.